How to create an .so library in Android studio?
I would like to create a standalone shared library, .so file in Android studio with C++. If I create a new native C++ project, that also compiles into an apk. Should I create a module to compile into .so?

You will find the *.sos in the build tree - one for each supported platform.  The apk is just a zip file with additional meta-data.  You can rename it and extract it to get at the .so files it contains.
